# Are all connected and locally integral affine schemes globally integral?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, noetherian, affine-schemes

In [these](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-726-algebraic-geometry-spring-2009/lecture-notes/MIT18_726s09_lec11_more_schemes.pdf) notes, on p. 2 Section 4, Kedlaya claims an affine scheme is integral if and only if it is connected and every local ring is an integral domain. But elsewhere I have seen that this requires a Noetherian condition on the affine scheme, e.g. problem 19 [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0708-216/216ps05.pdf), problem 56D in [this](https://usamo.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/napkin-2017-08-15.pdf).

What is wrong with Kedlaya's proof? Or is the result actually true without assuming Noetherian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the exercise referred to in the first paragraph: it is not necessarily true that the set of $x$ such that $f$ is nonzero in $O_{X,x}$ is open.  In fact, this can fail even if $A$ is Noetherian.  For instance, let $k$ be a field and take $A=k[x,y]/(xy)$, so $X$ is the union of two lines intersecting at a point.  Then the set where $x$ is locally nonzero is one of the lines, which is not open since it contains no neighborhood of the intersection points.

For a counterexample to the result without the Noetherian hypothesis, see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0568.